# How to "transfer" variables down the promise chain in node express router?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, promise, router

I am trying to make two separate DB calls in a promise chain, although for testing purposes, the first call is replaced by a simple string that gets passed along.

My problem is that I can't access the variable msg in my second promise (where I try to set context.foo = msg.

```
router.route("/")
.get(function(request, response) {

    var session = request.session;

    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

        resolve("h!");

    }).then(function(msg){

        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

            Snippet.find({}, function(error, data) {
                let context = {
                    snippets: data.map(function(snippet) {
                        return {
                            name: snippet.name,
                            snippet: snippet.snippet,
                            createdAt: snippet.createdAt,
                            user: snippet.user,
                            id: snippet._id
                        };
                    }),
                  foo: msg
                };
                resolve(context);
            });
        });

    }).then(function(context){
        response.render("start/index", context);
    }).catch(function(err){
        response.end(err);
    });
});
```

Another attempt, here trying to bind the router to the promise...

```
 router.route("/")
.get(function(request, response) {

    var session = request.session;

    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

        resolve("hi!");

    }).then(function(msg){

        router.msg = msg;

        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

            Snippet.find({}, function(error, data) {
                let context = {
                    snippets: data.map(function(snippet) {
                        return {
                            name: snippet.name,
                            snippet: snippet.snippet,
                            createdAt: snippet.createdAt,
                            user: snippet.user,
                            id: snippet._id
                        };
                    }),
                  foo: this.msg
                };
                resolve(context);
            }.bind(router));
        });
```

A third attempt...

```
router.route("/")
.get(function(request, response) {

    var session = request.session;

    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

        context.msg = "hi!";

        resolve(context);

    }).then(function(context){

        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            Snippet.find({}, function(error, data) {
                context.snippets = {
                    snippets: data.map(function(snippet) {
                        return {
                            name: snippet.name,
                            snippet: snippet.snippet,
                            createdAt: snippet.createdAt,
                            user: snippet.user,
                            id: snippet._id
                        };
                    }),
                };
                resolve(context);
            });
        });

    }).then(function(context){
        response.render("start/index", context);
    }).catch(function(err){
        response.end(err);
    });
});
```

So the basic problem is always, how can I "inject" or make use of a variable inside the Promise scope, when I have no surrounding object, no "this" to attaach it to =)

Comment: First code snippet looks ok, it should work. You can try to trace `msg` using `console.log` to understand, what's happening. You can take a look at simplify jsfiddle version for your code: https://jsfiddle.net/pogLza0q/

Comment: You need `if(error) reject(error);` in the `Snippet.find()` callback. An error at that point may or may not be the issue, but the `reject()` should be there anyway.

Comment: I'd go with a [bluebird coroutine](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.coroutine.html) here. It'll make your life simpler.

Answer (score 1):

Using bluebird's powerful **[`Promise.coroutine()`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.coroutine.html)**:

```
router.route("/")
.get(Promise.coroutine(function*(request, response) {
    try {
        const dbResult1 = yield getValueFromDatabaseAsync(/* w/e */);
        const dbResult2 = yield getValueFromDatabaseAsync(/* w/e, can be dbResult1 */);

        const context = {...}; // use dbResult1 and dbResult2 here normally
        response.render("start/index", context);
    } catch (err) {
        response.end(err);
    }
}));
```